# Remove certain characters in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I ran this command in shell script-

```
echo grep datadir /etc/my.cnf
```

this is the output i got-

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

What should I do to get the output as-

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: The output does not match the command you posted. Either the `echo` is wrong, or you have omitted a (useless) pair of backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ echo $str
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ echo ${str#*=}
/var/lib/mysql
```

Read more about these operations at the [ABS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output of the grep in a cut:

```
$ echo 'datadir=/var/lib/mysql' | cut -d '=' -f 2
/var/lib/mysql
```

You might run with problems if there are spaces in your file though (note the indent on the output):

```
$ echo 'datadir =  /var/lib/mysql' | cut -d '=' -f 2
  /var/lib/mysql
```

You could use awk to circumvent this:

```
$ echo 'datadir =  /var/lib/mysql' | awk -F '[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*' '{print $2}'
/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

use `cut` with the -d option

```
grep datadir /etc/my.cnf | cut -d = -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it through `sed 's/^datadir=//'` which means "replace the leading `datadir=` with nothing".

Comment: Or better yet only use `sed -n 's/^datadir=//p' /etc/my.cnf` without any `grep` or `echo`.